# Applet and Object Tag JSP interaction

Tags: java, javascript, applet, japplet

I have an  applet in a web application (JSP page) in one domain somedomain/myjsp.jsp embedded via object tag and i have another object tag in the same jsp which loads some other domain url  anotherdomain/another.jsp .I am unable to call the applet function from the jsp page of another domain.

```
function enableToUpdate() 
    {
     window.parent.document.MyApplet.EnableButton();               
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, the jsp is runing in the server jvm.
The applet is running in the client jvm.

This are two diferent programs in two different jvms. One can not call a function in the other.

You can use JavaScript:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html

Comment: the above function is an javascript function .On click of button i invoke the function.but the same result.it cant find the applet which is on another domain.Any workaround?Also if i run both on the same domain it invokes.